# InteractiveBrokers API: an instrument's market state?

Tags: interactive-brokers, ibpy

I try to find a way to receive the current market state and changes to the market state of a tradeable instrument through IB's API.

For example, I try to get a notification when TSLA moves from market-closed to pre-opening auction and then to the regular trading session, likewise during the day.

The only bit I found so far is https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html#halted - which gives me a "market halted" indication. That's not what I look for, markets can also go into an auction state throughout a trading session.

I can't find any reference to market states in IB's API. Any solution anyone?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think the best you can do is access the TradingHours property of the ContractDetails class. Parse the string and compare it to the current time.

Comment: yeah, problem with this approach is that the trading hours are not reflecting any intraday issues that might arise. and it also doesn't tell me how and when preopen auction and thelike start and end ... but thanks

Comment: After a halt, markets go to auction at a certain time. Most likely you need to specify this manually, so when a halt tickType is received, you might want to query a resource for the type of halt, then you'd know when the auction will happen.